# correlation between monthly precipitation and tree ring data

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a correlation analysis between monthly average precipitation and tree-ring data. My tree-ring data (stretching from 1884 to 2019) is in a single-column format with years as rows whilst my precipitation data (stretching from 1950 to 2019 ) is in the matrix format with years as rows and months as columns. Is it okay to just use these data frames in these two different formats, or I have to do something, please advise. Also, when I try to run the dcc function, I'm getting an error: Error in is.finite(if (is.character(from)) from <- as.numeric(from) else from) :
default method not implemented for type 'list'. I don't know what it means and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone please help?

```
#CODE
library(dplR)
library(treeclim)
library("TRADER")
library(utils)
library(ggplot2)
library(graphics)

# AF28OFINAL
# read in measurements
chaf28o6 <- read.rwl("F:/Obby/PhD/untitled folder/Dendrochronology/all/AF28OFINAL/chaf28o6.rwl")

#
rwl.report(chaf28o6)
#
plot(chaf28o6, plot.type="spag")
# detrending all the series in the chaf2806 at once
chaf28o6.rwl <- detrend(rwl = chaf28o6, method = "Friedman")

#descriptive statistics
rwl.stats(chaf28o6[1:17])
#Building a Mean Value Chronology
chaf28o6.crn <- chron(chaf28o6.rwl, prefix = "CAM")

library(readr)
clim <- read_csv("Abies2800.csv")
View(clim)
##response function analysis in treeclim - modeled after Dendroclim2002.
##Can take dynamic = "static", "moving", "evolving"
resp <- dcc(chrono = chaf28o6.crn, climate = clim, selection = 1:10,
            method = "correlation", dynamic = "static", win_size = 35, win_offset = 1, start_last = TRUE,
            timespan = NULL, var_names = NULL, ci = 0.05, boot = "std", sb = FALSE)
```

Comment: What is `type(chaf28o6.crn)` and the same for `clim`? Also, I recommend using `read.csv2` for reading CSV files into datagrams.

Comment: chaf28o6.crn is a .crn data format (tree ring chronology) frame created from a .rwl file, you can check the code. The clim file is a CSV format (precipitation data) with years as row names and months as column names, forming a matrix.